# Terraform & S3 lifecycle: How to expire specific objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-s3

I am writing this S3 bucket lifecycle rule:

```
 lifecycle_rules = [
    {
      id      = "log"
      enabled = true
      prefix  = "log/"

      tags = {
        "rule"      = "log"
        "autoclean" = "true"
      }
      expiration = {
        days = 365
      }
    }
  ]
```

An ASCII mock diagram of the bucket is provided below: Logs are dynamically written everyday in this bucket. Some in the folder `logs/`, some in the subfolder `failed_logs/` and some on the root folder of the bucket.

```
BUCKET/
|
  nonlogfile.exe
  log_file_that_i_DONT_wanna_delete.log
  logs/ 
      |
       file1     (Created 2021-01-01)
       file2     (Created 2021-01-02)
       failed_logs/
                  |
                   file3 (Created 2021-01-03) 
                   file4 (Created 2021-01-04)
```

My target is to expire everyfile in the `log/` folder (and its subfolder `failed_logs` after 365 days.

```
`file1` would expire at 2022-01-01
`file2` would expire at 2022-01-02
`file3` would expire at 2022-01-03
`file4` would expire at 2022-01-04
```

whereas

```
nonlogfile.exe
log_file_that_i_DONT_wanna_delete.log
```

would never expire.

Terraform's [aws_s3_bucket documentation](https://registry:.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket#filter) states that:

> The `lifecycle_rule` object supports the following:
>
> `prefix` - (Optional) Object key prefix identifying one or more objects to which the rule applies.
>
> `tags` - (Optional) Specifies object tags key and value.

- I don't understand the `prefix` attribute
- My files are not tagged

How can I target them as explained above, based on their location on the bucket?

Comment: Are you saying the prefix youre using doesnt work?

Comment: I am saying that I cannot understand what this attribute is supposed to do. What is an Object key prefix? Does it apply to folders? E.g will adding `prefix = 'log'` target all the files in the log folder and all the files in all the subfolders of the log folder?

Comment: The prefix `log` will not apply to all files recursively in the directory, it will be looking for a file called `log` and only apply to that file.  However an prefix value of `log/` will recursively apply to all files within that "directory" and "subdirectories" ( I put the word directory in quotes because they aren't actually directories they are prefixes ).   `log/` is the correct prefix assuming the log dir as at the root of your bucket

Comment: Thank you Chris. This is very helpful, if you want to post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## S3 Structure Explained

The prefix attribute is simply the path to your s3 object minus the bucket name.  If you had the following S3 "directory" `s3://ec-integration-files/logs/` the prefix value would simply be `logs/`.

The attribute is named *prefix* as opposed to *path* because while s3 looks like a directory tree structure technically it is flat storage.  However the Management Console displays the objects as if they are stored in a directory structure, and it uses the prefixes to do this.

> One other point of clarification, you can have two objects at the root ( or at any depth ) named `logs` and `logs/`.  One of these will be displayed as a directory in the management console and the other as a file object, but they are really just two objects with different names